# Combine 2 function javascript into 1

Tags: javascript

```
function showRole(str,x)
        {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("txtHintrole"+x+"").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHintrole"+x+"").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/tes/index.php/form/role/"+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

```
function showUser(str,x)
        {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("txtHint"+x+"").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint"+x+"").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/tes/index.php/form/hint/"+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

can i join this 2 function into 1
because i need both of them to show data
and i dont know how to set 2 function with this

> newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("onchange","showUser(this.value,"+xx+");");

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Do you want to execute them both together (like in McGarnagle's answer), or do you want to make them more [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: `setAttribute("onchange", "…` - arghh! Read http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just create a wrapper function:

```
var showBoth = function(str, x) {
    showRole(str, x);
    showUser(str, x);
};
```

Comment: where should i put this code?
inside showuser? or new function

Comment: @JohanesChan new function, next to the other two.